# Hierarchical clustering in python with numpy/pandas only

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical

I am really new to python and data science and I could really do with some help, please.
I have a dataframe with 440 observations and 6 describing variables. I am supposed to do a hierarchical clustering of the data, but ONLY with the help of numpy and pandas packages. I cannot use scipy or sklearn. So far, I was able to create the distance matrix (440x440 numpy array). I want only two clusters. Concerning the linkage method I want to use ward linkage, but centroid method would also be ok. How can I create two clusters out of the distance matrix based on the linkage criteria? I thought of something like "find the smallest distance, put the corresponding column/row value in one cluster, remove them from the distance matrix, re-do until the old matrix is empty and I have got a new matrix with tuples of as row/column index, and re-do that until I have only 2 rows/columns left which include all my original observations..."

I know, that´s not a good description but as I said I am really new to this and I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for SciPy's hierarchical clustering? https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py#L2424-L2608 You can see how they have done it and try to go from there. This sounds an awful lot like homework, so take the time to read through this.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without sklearn or scipy. Why not just use what you're given, which is free. What's next? You need to do clustering but you're not allowed to use a computer?